# Change TD innerHTML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a table with multiple TD's, all of which have the id="changeMe"

`<td id="changeMe" runat=server>here is my value</td>`

Im using the following code in C#

`HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)this.Page.FindControl("changeMe");
                cell.InnerHtml.Replace("value", "newvalue");`

However, I get a null exception. How do I find and then replace the contents of a TD in C#?

Basically, I want to change part of the TDs html to the new values.

Comment: ID `changeMe` does not match with `FindControl("contType")`.

Comment: @Scorpion :Oops, my mistake on typing my example. They do match in my source code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `Replace` function **returns** a string, it does not modify it.

Second, rather than using `FindControl`, you should just be able to refer to the control by it's ID, it should be available for manipulation in your code behind (because of `runat="server"`), like this:

```
changeMe.InnerHtml = changeMe.InnerHtml.Replace("value", "newvalue");
```

Answer (score -1):

also you can try using the grid view instead. That way you just have to ::

```
dataGridView1[1,1].value="tes";
```